# What does "pins-out view" mean?

Tags: jtag, jargon

I am reading the wikipedia article about the [JTAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG#History). It says:

> In the 1980s, multi-layer circuit boards and non-lead-frame integrated
>   circuits (ICs) were becoming standard and connections were being made
>   between ICs that were not available to probes. The majority of
>   manufacturing and field faults in circuit boards were due to poor
>   solder joints on the boards, imperfections in board connections, or
>   the bonds and bond wires from IC pads to pin lead frames. The Joint
>   Test Action Group (JTAG) was formed in 1985 to provide a ***pins-out view***
>   from one IC pad to another so these faults could be discovered.

So what does the ***pins-out view*** mean?

(PS. I am just moving into the EE world, appreciate if plain English is used. :) )

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply, it allows (provided a test port at each end is provided) to test an interconnect.

Consider a [complex processor](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/power-architecture-processors/powerquicc-processors/powerquicc-iii-85xx/powerquicc-iii-processor-with-ddr2-pci-pci-express-serial-rapidio-serdes-1-gb-ethernet-security:MPC8548E) that has a large [flash memory](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/parallel/m29ew/m29ew_256mb_2gb.pdf); we want to know that it is both properly soldered and can be accessed for both read and write to enable [in-system programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-system_programming), to name but one use case.

JTAG permits a view along the signal chain that cannot be physically probed.

This can extend in almost unlimited ways - if a test port exists at both ends of a digital signal chain, the a set of signals asserted at one end could be read (quite possibly having had some gating between test ports) to verify both the interconnect and functionality (at least at low speeds, although test port frequencies are now achieving 50MHz bit rates).

So we are looking at an entire signal chain from the edge pins of a function, through a number of PCB nodes on other logic in the signal path.

The *pins out view* is simply looking at the edge pins to verify solder joints and functionality through an entire path.

Interestingly, there is a push to get the same test capability for [analogue](http://www.jtag.com/en/content/ieee-11494)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is very well formulated either. But what is meant is that the pins of each ICs can be set and tested (the pin states can be sent **out** to the JTAG probe - hence the *pin-**out** view* term, I imagine).

This is the primary aim of JTAG, actually. It was not to provide means to debug a processor (reading resgisters, accessing internal memory, ...), this usage came later. The initial aim was just to be able to test fully assembled boards.

This is called *boundary scan*. The principle is simple: you tell the chips to output some arbitrary level on some of their pins (bypassing the usual pin functionality), and you read these levels from the chip on the other side of the PCB traces. This way, you ensure that the PCB traces are not broken and that the solder joints are fine.

You can easily automate all this and you can quickly check a whole board with lots of connections between chips. And since you know which traces are bad in case of failure, rework is much easier.

This functionality has other applications than just testing: you could for example use it to initialize some EEPROM, by forcing the generation of the required WRITE command sequences on the appropriate pins of the processor to which it is connected. This can be done without needing specific code in the firmware. Basically, you can do all sort of hacks with this, either to test or to fix boards.

Answer (score -1):

"Pins out view" doesn't appear to be standard jargon.  A Google search pulled up 55 references to the phrase, all of which were related to JTAG.

It seems this phrase began in a JTAG reference work before being copied on to other derivative documents.  My understanding from the context of the Wikipedia article is that 'pins out view' simply describes an otherwise internal signal being available on an output pin.

Comment: That would be incorrect.  It's probably not a good idea to try to append answers to two year old questions already having answers, where yours is based on a web search and guess.  If you want to understand the actual subject, look up boundary scan.

Comment: It may not be standard jargon but it is effectively what is happening.  Chip scale and BGA packaging means not all pins are accessed by a board tester, effectively hidden pins, so JTAG was invented to access and test these hidden pins.  Pins out view cannot test them.